# Wp admin bar not showing when logged in without ssl

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

Here is the url 
http://fetchasite.com/love/
So  I have migrated the wordpress and now customizing but this one issue keeps bugging me . I am able to login to the admin but when i go to frontend its does not logs in  and its not even showing the admin bar . It only shows the admin bar when i use https in the url . I have checked all the stuff in the database everything is correct but this one issue  wasting my time
Please help i am begging you my friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site treated as two different domains. 
1) With ssl
2) Without ssl

You need to move whole site with ssl by replacing all url from http to https then it ll work fine.